# Как добавить на страницу вертикальную линию?

Tags: html

Как добавить на страницу вертикальную линию?

Comment: Я конечно может ошибаюсь, но наверное в вопросе нужно было написать как построить горизонтальную линию, а не вертикальную.

Comment: @kvax Вы ошибаетесь, я интересовался именно вертикальной линией. Оказалось, что её можно построить, меняя параметры width и size. То есть если <hr width='1px' size='30px' color="black"> вертикальная линия, а если значения size и width поменять местами, будет горизонтальная. Ну, и плюс поправка на border-style:none, иначе линия будет слишком толстая. И возможно, нашлись бы способы сделать это каким-то другим тегом, например. С горизонтальной линией всё предельно ясно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<hr width="50%" size="4" color="black">
```

Comment: точно! только еще в стиль еще border-style:none нужно добавить

Answer (score 5):

В стили:

```
#vert{
    height:100% // или сколько нужно в пикселях или процентах
    width: 1px;
    border:none;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

В html:

```
<div id="vert"></div>
```

Также в стилях позиционировать как угодно, установить пунктир или еще как-нибудь поиздеваться.